# jQuery getting selected options issue

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have 2 multi-select boxes that transfer to each other. The transfer both ways goes fine. I also call an ajax fn to submit the selected options to a database.
The call from left to right works fine because I am just getting all the options, not just selected ones.

```
var domelts = $('#imfavs option');
// next translate that into an array of just the values
var buddylist = $.map(domelts, function(elt, i) { return $(elt).val();});
```

Now, when I try to go from right to left with just the selected options, it's always returning an empty array.

I tried 2 ways

```
var domelts = $('#imfavs :selected');
var removelist = $.map(domelts, function(elt, i) { return $(elt).val();});

$('#imfavs :selected').each(function (x) {
   removelist[x] = $(this).val();
});
```

for the 2nd one, removelist is var'd before.

My HTML

```
        <form  method="post" name="frmFavs" id="frmFavs">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Current Friends</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>SLS Chat Friends</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="userfavs" multiple="multiple" size="25" id="userfavs">
                            <cfoutput query="userfavs"><option value="#encrypt(userfavs.user2id,application.key,'DES','Hex')#">#userfavs.user2#</option></cfoutput>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" style="height:100px;" id="add">&gt;</button><br />
                        <button type="button" style="height:100px;" id="remove">&lt;</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="imfavs" multiple="multiple" size="25" id="imfavs"></select>
                    </td>
                <td valign="middle"><div id="info"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
var domelts = $('#imfavs :selected');
```

try

```
var domelts = $('#imfavs option:selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and it seemed to work ok.

Check and make sure the options have value attributes.

`<option value="value1">value1</option>`